# Identify a short story about a kid with a tribe of celts living in her hair.

Tags: story-identification

The girl believed she could hear a tribe of miniature Celts in her hair .Has the phrase,"the druids are predicting disaster"

Comment: I used to read this one. Give me a minute and I might remember the title.

Answer (score 7):

Be warned that I've never read that story myself, so this answer is not based on personal recollection. But I got curious enough to do a little Googling, and I quickly found that, according to some other online commentators, **Joan Aiken** once wrote a short story with that premise: [**"Who Goes Down This Dark Road?"**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?98858)

The story was one of several collected in the Joan Aiken anthology *A Touch of Chill*. According to one of the online reviews of that book [on Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0440204593), that story may be summarized this way:

> "Who Goes Down This Dark Road?" is another darkly amusing story, about
> a young girl who believes that she has a tribe of Gauls living in her
> hair. For a six year old, her knowledge on the subject is remarkable,
> and she relates the message that a catastrophe is coming...

Since I haven't read the thing myself, I wanted some confirmation from a second source before I posted this. I kept Googling, and found some other descriptions of that story which say much the same. For instance, an [online discussion forum](http://vaultofevil.proboards.com/thread/1211/mark-ronson-beaver-book-horror) devoted to British horror fiction contains the following summary of "Who Goes Down This Dark Road?" from a poster called "dem bones":

> Six year old Amanda King is the most punctual, best-behaved girl in
> Mr. Thorneycroft's class, noted for her "shiny, neat and symmetrically
> plaited" blond hair - until she hacks most of it off and buries it in
> the back garden. The new look doesn't suit at all, but, as she
> patiently explains to her teacher, she had to get rid of her plaits as
> there are people living on top of her head, namely a tribe of ancient
> Gauls running from Caesar. Recently one of their Druids has prophesied
> that a great catastrophe will soon befall them. A drunk driver proves
> him right.

So I do believe this must be the tale you were remembering. (I've read a few of Joan Aiken's story collections, but I must have missed *A Touch of Chill*.)

Comment: Thanks so much , tbat is it. I had been trying to remember this for over thirty years

Comment: I know the feeling. A very similar problem was what led me to discover this site, some months ago, and post my first question on it! (And most of my subsequent questions have also been cases of trying to track down something I know I read back in the 1980s or 1990s.)